# How do I implement a multicast client in NIO.2?

Tags: java, nio, multicast

How would an example of using a Java 7 NIO.2 multicast client look like? I could only find half of an example in the [MulticastChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/MulticastChannel.html) documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example works. Note that `DatagramChannel.join()` requires a `NetworkInterface` to work.

```java
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("239.255.0.1")

DatagramChannel dc = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET)
    .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
    .bind(new InetSocketAddress(5000))
    .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_IF, ni);
MembershipKey key = dc.join(group, ni);

ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1500);
while (true) {
    if (key.isValid()) {
        byteBuffer.clear();
        InetSocketAddress sa = (InetSocketAddress) dc.receive(byteBuffer);
        byteBuffer.flip();

        System.out.println("Multicast received from " + sa.getHostString());

        // TODO: Parse message
    }
}
```

Comment: is multicast supported by of majority hardware? What if doesn't?

Comment: Whether multicast works or not depends on the underlying network stack. I guess that DatagramChannel.join() should throw an exception if the system doesn't support multicast, but that may be implementation specific.

Comment: Thanks Sundae for this minimally concise (blocking) nio example - exactly what the doctor ordered! +1